# Computer not allowing all monitors to display

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have 3, 4k monitors plugged into a 4070ti. 2 are running at 60hz, 1 is running at 120hz. I have a 4th monitor that used as a sensor panel 1920x480 which shows up in the display preferences but is greyed out. Doesn't seem like windows will allow operation on the smaller screen. When I deactivate one of the other monitors, the sensor panel will work. It seems my system only wants to run 3 monitors with the current resolution. When I only had 2, 4k monitors along with 2, 1920 monitors, all 4 worked fine. I wondered if the card was bottlenecking res. so I added smaller video card, just to run the sensor panel, still nothing. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/10bntq5/comment/j4cvw8k/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), it'd seem that both 30 and 40 series are limited to output up to 8k60hz at once. You can split that several ways. Here are some examples:

- 4 monitors at 4k60hz
- 2 monitors at 4k120hz
- 2 monitors at 4k60hz + 1 monitor at 4k120hz ( just like now )

It'd seem that you're at the GPU's limit. You can find some cheap old GPU for a secondary, to run the fourth monitor, and it should work.

Comment: Answered my own question. Apparently my 4070ti can not handle multiple display port connects with the number of 4k monitors I have. The fix, 2 cards, 2 Dports, 2 hdmi. 1 DP and HDMI on each card, done and working well.

Comment: Software limitations are do ridiculous. Glad it's working!